# Advanced Search and Replace for .module.css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance, css-modules

I was using the conventional  `import './App.css'` and just use className to effect the styling for my react application.
I structured my react app to have a dashboard view component that renders the various dashboard components (profile, stats etc) so I had to import all the dashboard components to the view component and Link them using `Routes`.
But I noticed that the dashboard view wasn't displaying as I wanted it to, so I went to the inspect tab and to my surprise **ALL** the css styling of **ALL** the imported components which had corresponding classNames were affecting each other. So I decided to use `.module.css` which would render the styling exclusively, but this is my problem... my code is **HEAVY** and it is unproductive to change `className="tool-links flex-column"` to  `` className={`${styles.tool-links} ${styles.flex-column}`} `` one after the other by hand.
Is there any tool I could use to do this over thousands of lines of codes effectively? Thank you. Pardon any typos

Comment: looks like a problem that source-graph can solve: `https://about.sourcegraph.com/`
It isn't guaranteed to give the best result though IMO.
Also, moving to CSS modules is a fundamental change in your application and having to do it by manually is nothing but a consequence of that. If it looks tiresome, it's supposed to be

Comment: Thats true in some way, but I think it could be worked on, If I wanted a css styleguide to affect a component I would have imported it. I dont think stylesheets should affect pages by default unless they are imported directly

Answer (score 0):

Having pondered about this question for 24 hours I discovered a walkaround.
Instead of changing from conventional css styling to css modules, I could just add a prefix to the class names to differentiate every styling from each other e.g( `className="content"` now becomes `className="edit-profile-content"` and no two classNames would be the same, and this could be done easily with VSCode Find and Replace tool. I think it's just common sense.